# ASP.net default login.aspx page missing images

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am using the default ASP.Net Web Application in visual studio 2010. When starting the site and going to the login page, it is missing all of the graphics. After logging in the graphics return.

I have tried adding exceptions for the path in web.config with no luck. Maybe I have the wrong path? I am using the default styles.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
...

<location path="~/Account/Login.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

The site is the default new ASP.Net Web Application in visual studio 2010 plus  in the web.config

Comment: Are your graphics referenced relatively or absolutely?

Comment: I would hope visual studio would set the defaults as relative. How do I check this? I would think this is more of authorization issue rather than a location as the graphics work fine if I am logged in.

Comment: Do you have custom permissions specified on folders in the web.config? Verify that your images folder doesn't have permissions set that would deny access from users that aren't authenticated. See this link for what I'm talking about if you aren't clear: http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx

Comment: i.e. do you set the src of your images = "~/images/myimage.jpg", "http://www.mysite.com/images/myimage.jpg", or "/images/myimage.jpg"?

Comment: I am using the default style sheet with the example project in Styles/Site.css It doesnt use any images files. I have tried to allow access for all users to the style sheet but it still doesnt display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a formatting/syntax issue.

When allow access in Web.config it should be:

```
<location path="Styles">
```

Not

```
<location path="~/Styles">
```